# A humorous guy who is always looking for funny things to laugh

Tags: phrase-request

Imagine a very humorous guy who is always looking for something to laugh at it. How do you describe such a person?
Does my mentioned sentence sound natural to you:

> - He is always looking for something to laugh at it.

Comment: Removing 'it' makes it sound better, I think. **"He is always looking for something to laugh at."**

Answer (score 1):

Some small problems with your expression:

> something to laugh at

is sufficient, you don't need the **it** on the end, you have taken the phrase "laugh at something" and inverted it "something to laugh at".

Second, to laugh at something can on occasion be unpleasant or unsympathetic: bullies laugh at less capable people. So if possible I'd like to avoid "laugh at", except when saying clearly we are laughing at something appropriate.

> Dave tells great jokes, people always laugh at them.

Another small issue is that it may make the person seem rather shallow, They are only interested in finding something amusing? I think the flavour is more that

a). they welcome other peoples humour
b). they are ready to laugh at themselves; I say something stupid, realise I've said and find humour in my error.

We might say

> He can always see the funny side of things
>
> He does love a good joke

Or

> He's a good laugh

which implies that he brings humour to a group of people

Comment: Thank you very much @djna , but your second founded issue was exactly what I was going to describe it; I ws talking about a person who's shallow and behaves not in a good manner.